# Best way to get all substrings matching a RegExp in Dart

Tags: regex, dart

I want to get a list of substrings matching a RegExp in a string. What is the best way to do this?

RegExp object from dart:core has `Iterable<Match> allMatches(String input, [int start=0])` method. This is kind of what I need, but I want to get Iterable of Strings, not matches.

There is also method `String stringMatch(String input)`, which returns a String, but only a first match.

So I wrote myslef this function using `map`:

```dart
Iterable<String> _allStringMatches(String text, RegExp regExp) {
  Iterable<Match> matches = regExp.allMatches(text);
  List<Match> listOfMatches = matches.toList();

  // TODO: there must be a better way to get list of Strings out of list of Matches
  Iterable<String> listOfStringMatches = listOfMatches.map((Match m) {
    return m.input.substring(m.start, m.end);
  });

  return listOfStringMatches;
}
```

but it seems to me that it is pretty basic functionality and I can't believe it is not in anywhere in the API. I guess there must be a better way to do such a basic task.

Comment: Can you post an example string and what substrings you want? You can just iterate over all the Matches and get `group(n)`, with n=0 for the whole match and other n's for parts.

Comment: `group(0)` of the match returns the whole string matched. You can simplify a little bit your code by using it.

Comment: See my post, @fog :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your regexp contains **only one group** (like `new RegExp(r'(\S+)')`) you can rewrite your function to:

```dart
Iterable<String> _allStringMatches(String text, RegExp regExp) => 
    regExp.allMatches(text).map((m) => m.group(0));
```

Comment: Even shorter: `regexp.allMatches(text).map((m)=>m[0])`.